# Hide all rows except the one that is being edited in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I want to reduce the probability of users editing the wrong record so once they start editing one row in datagridview i want to hide all rows.

I tried this:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvr in rdGridView.Rows)
{
    if (dgvr.Index != e.RowIndex )
    {
        dgvr.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.DarkGray;
        dgvr.ReadOnly = true
    }
}
```

But this doesn't give much of a protection.

I can update the DataView to only show that row and assign the dataview again to the datgridview but that would take the focus out of the cell, and cell doesn't go into edit mode.

Doing dgvr.Visible = false in a foreach loop like above also gives exception

Comment: I would ask: why use a DataGridView for this then? Seems more like a ListView would have been more appropriate, with editable fields. I don't think the approach of hiding all of the rows is a great solution. Did the ReadOnly not work? You said it's not "much of a protection", but if they can't edit it, that sounds like what you're asking for.

Comment: I said its not much of a protection because, when user double clciks it changing the ReadOnly field takes cell out of edit mode

Comment: Can you keep the index of the cell in a variable, iCurrentCellIndex, and then put that cell back into EditMode after you change the ReadOnly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find anything better than making all the rows read only and turning them gray except the one being edited.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try loading your data in the DataGridView, but using fields to load the data from the row you want to edit. This way, you can set the DataGridView to ReadOnly, and on click, you can copy the data from the editable fields to textboxes, allowing the user to edit and save.

Comment: I thought about this too, having an "editing panel" of sorts, but I went back to: why use a dgv if you're not going to allow editing for which it's intended. You can just display data in any number of controls if you don't want open editing.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a bit more different solution. On a double click on a row (no matter which cell if you intend to edit whole cells of a row) you open a new Form (small window) which will have textBoxes inside and a button Save. The number of textBoxes depends on the number of columns to edit. 
So pass all the data from DGV to the constructor of this new form and pass the data to according textBoxes.

So this way you can edit all the data seperated from the DGV. And btw, when showing new Form, use ShowDialog() method which will create this new form editable only (before closing it, user will not be able to do anyting else but edit data on this form).